# Ansible playbooks stop running on new Ubuntu 20.04 box (Ansible 2.10 / Python 3.8.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ansible

One of my playbook ran ok on the following setup

```
ansible 2.9.11  config file = None  configured module search path = ['/home/alice/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible  python version = 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

Things broke, however, when I moved the same playbook to the following setup

```
ansible 2.10.2
  config file = /home/bob/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/bob/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

I got the following error and am trying to figure out if it is the new python version, the Ansible version, or maybe the Ansible Galaxy module version (upgraded from Fortinet.Fortimanager 1.0.5 to 2.0.0, but when I force install 1.0.5, I get another error, which makes me think this isn't the main issue)

```
TASK [Add model device] ******************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible_collections.fortinet.fortimanager.plugins.module_utils.common.FMGBaseException: An attempt was made at communicating with a FMG with no valid session and an unexpected error was discovered.
fatal: [fmg01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_ekiptyph/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortimanager/plugins/modules/fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 351, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_ekiptyph/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py\", line 195, in __rpc__\nansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: An attempt was made at communicating with a FMG with no valid session and an unexpected error was discovered.\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/bob/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12942ssko667z/ansible-tmp-1603819794.3367019-13026-201727037698625/AnsiballZ_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/bob/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12942ssko667z/ansible-tmp-1603819794.3367019-13026-201727037698625/AnsiballZ_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/bob/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12942ssko667z/ansible-tmp-1603819794.3367019-13026-201727037698625/AnsiballZ_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.fortinet.fortimanager.plugins.modules.fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 207, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 97, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 87, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_ekiptyph/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortimanager/plugins/modules/fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 362, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_ekiptyph/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortimanager/plugins/modules/fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 356, in main\nansible_collections.fortinet.fortimanager.plugins.module_utils.common.FMGBaseException: An attempt was made at communicating with a FMG with no valid session and an unexpected error was discovered.\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Any suggestions on how I isolate this given the output error?

Here is the playbook in question (super simple)

```
---
- name: Add model device to FMG and install Policy Package
  hosts: fmg01
  #  gather_facts: no
  connection: httpapi
  collections:
    - fortinet.fortimanager

  tasks:
    - name: Add model device
      fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device:
        loose_validation: true
        method: exec
        params:
          - data:
              adom: root
              device:
                # device action: add_model
                mgmt_mode: 'fmg'
                #os_ver: 6
                #mr: 4
                sn: FGVM01TMxxxxxxxx
                adm_pass: 'password'
                adm_usr: 'admin'
                ip: '192.168.0.100'
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, the problem seems to be that the following item was missing from Fortinet Fortimanager:

```
config system admin user
edit admin
set rpc-permit read-write
end
```